# As a foreign resident of Brazil, can I always fly domestically using only my Alien Identity Card?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, brazil, polish-citizens

I'm a Polish citizen living in Brazil. When travelling in Brazil I'm usually using a government issued ID with RNE number (*Registro Nacional dos Estrangeiros* - National Registry of Foreigners). I have a passport, but I prefer to leave it at home.

Next week I'm going to catch a domestic flight (São Paulo - Recife) with LATAM airlines. Their website has a section with [valid documents needed for domestic travel](https://www.latam.com/en_us/tam-check-in-and-other-services/check-in-tam/), and for foreigners it mentions:

- Overseas passport.
- **National Alien Registration (Registro Nacional de Estrangeiro, RNE) or Alien Identity Card (Cédula de Identidade de Estrangeiro, CIE)**.
- Diplomatic or consular identity.
- Any other legal travel document issued pursuant to international agreements signed by Brazil.

However, when I'm trying to check-in on LATAM's website, it only allows me to use my passport as a travel document:

[image: check-in screen]

Is their website wrong, not allowing me to put a valid travel document? Can I be sure that when I go to the airport, I'll be able to check-in only with my RNE?

Comment: Living in Brazil you can use the RNE instead of a RG but you really needs a CPF and most sites and documents will require one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will be allowed to check in at the airport with your RNE instead of a passport - the website probably does not allow this because the RNE validity needs to be checked by a person.

The LATAM site is very clear that you can use an RNE in place of a passport for domestic travel.

For the sake of english language visitors, [the english language version of the page you link to is here](https://www.latam.com/en_us/tam-check-in-and-other-services/check-in-tam/).

Comment: Makes sense, the part I was the most curious about is why they wouldn't allow it during online check-in. I updated the link to point English version of the site.

Comment: @Kuba not just domestically, but internationally within the MEROSUL area too. That's right, you can leave your passport at home when going to (say) Argentina

Comment: What happens if OP types in the wrong number during check in? Would he be prevented from boarding?

Comment: @JonathanReez Can be a bit hard to type the wrong number because it's expecting a RG (registro geral,  default id for citizens)  or passport number and it both ahves checks digits. So typing ramdonly is likely to raise a "invalid RG/passport number"

Comment: @jean what if you pass the digits check but the number is wrong?

Comment: @JonathanReez Those number are calculated in a way if you type one or two wrong digits it's will generate a different check digit. Just by typing a random number you got 1% chance "colliding" a valid check digit. Anyway let's say you input your partner id number or you got incredible "lucky" and typed a totaly random valid number. I don't know. You will show a ID (with pícture) and the ticket. I guess the result dependes on the crew discretion